# How to use Linq SQL to perform INNER JOINs where values are equal or one is null

Tags: c#, sql, linq

How can I perform the following query using Linq

```
SELECT u.* FROM Users u   
INNER JOIN Localities l ON (u.State = l.State or l.State is NULL)
                       AND (u.City = l.City or l.City is NULL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try out the following query. Also to make it more optimize you can remove your null conditions as inner join will only work if both of the records contains value

```
            var users = from u in Users
                        join l in Localities on new { A = u.State, B = u.City} 
                        equals new { A = l.State, B = l.City }
                        select u
```

`l.State is NULL` and `l.city is null` will eliminated by default from inner joins so you don't need to make joins on null

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, you may need to change a bit as it is not tested.

```
var result = from Users u
            join Localities l
            on new { u.state, u.City } equals new { l.state, l.City }    
            where (l.state == NULL || l.City == NULL)   
            select u;
```